# Save audio files from remote URL and load them locally in AKPlayer

Tags: swift, caching, nsdata, nsfilemanager, audiokit

There are arrays of MP3 files on remote URL. What I'd like to try is to temporarily and selectively save them on user's device and play them with Audio Player (I'm experimenting with Audiokit's AKPlayer). Here's what I've written:

```
    guard let remote = URL(string: "http://myserver.com/test.mp3"),
       let data = NSData(contentsOf: remote) else {
            AKLog("Remote failed to load.")
            return
    }

    let cachedFile = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first as URL?
    try? data.write(to: remote)
    let player = AKPlayer(url: cachedFile!)

    AudioKit.output = player
    try? AudioKit.start()
```

This code only works when I assign AudioPlayer's url at local files. But in this version, it says `"failed call=ExtAudioFileOpenURL((CFURLRef)fileURL, &_extAudioFile"`. I am kind of stuck understanding downloading and loading remote files. Could anybody inform me about this? Much appreciated. <3

Comment: I think you'll need to wait for the file to exist on the device before loading it into AKPlayer.  Perhaps there is a completion callback for the download operation?